# Elasticsearch query too many results

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I'm tring to set up a simple search that would return me simple results with a custom ordering, the ordering i get back is fine based on a custom score.

The problem is that for this query

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": query_term,
        "fields": ["name_auto"],
    }
}
```

**NOTE: name_auto is an Edge N gram field on elastics**

I always get a result set also if the query does not make any sense.

Example:

I have an elastcisearch index populated with the name of all the android applications.
If i search for **face** i get back all the results related to it ordered by number of comments on the play store, menans [facebook, facebook messenger, ...]

The problem is that when i query for something like **facesomeuselesschars** i still get the same results as before but fore sure there is nothing that match "someuselesschars".

Can anybody help about

Comment: Perhaps your min gram size was large enough to match the start of your query, and your query was also being processed by the ngram analyzer?

Answer (score 4):

ElasticSearch will always return results that match your query, even if the score of those results are poor.  Your query for 'facesomeuselesschars' will match anything that has 'face' in it because of your ngrams (e.g. the first four characters of your query will be match multiple tokens in your index).

The rest of the characters in your query will simply lower the score of the returned match, but not prevent it from being returned.

If you want to set a minimum score that a result must reach, you can use the [min_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/min-score.html) parameter.

Comment: 8 years later, this saved my day. Thanks!